# Maximizing the value of a set of item pairs given limited numbers of items

Tags: algorithms

I have three types of items: $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$, each with quantities $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$. I can combine one of each of two different types of items 
(for example combining $a_1$ with $a_3$) into a product $p_{ij}$ which has a value of $v_{ij}$. The value of each product is not related to the individual items, but specifically to the combination of those items. 
With 3 types of items, there are only 3 possible products, but the number of products increase when given a generalized number of item types $a_n$.

How do I maximize the total value all items paired into products, given limited and differing quantities for each item?

I have been struggling for a way of formally conceptualizing this problem in order to find an algorithm that may work. I've spent time learning about knapsack and generalized assignment problems to see if I can fit this problem into one of those to no avail. A greedy algorithm will, of course, find a local max, and I will probably end up using that if I can't figure out anything better.

Comment: Have you had a look at [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Example)?

Comment: I had not.  I think that's what I'm looking for: Maximize:$$v_{12}p_{12}+v_{13}p_{13}+v_{23}p_{23}$$Subject to:$$a_{11}p_{12}+a_{12}p_{13} \le a_1$$$$a_{21}p_{12}+a_{22}p_{23}\le a_2$$$$a_{31}p_{13}+a_{32}p_{23} \le a_3$$

Comment: Glad to help! If you need additional guidance, I suggest asking a new  question outlining the problem, where you include the tag "linear-programming". I'm not an expert on the topic, but others are.

Comment: Will do, thanks.